# How to assign size of the table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanna adjust the size of the table column as per my wish. coding I used is below.

```
$('#Details').dataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    {
      "width": "30%",  
      "targets": 'no-sort', 
      "orderable": true
    },{
      "width": "10%", 
      "orderable": true,
    },{
      "width": "10%", 
      "orderable": true,
    },{
      "width": "10%", 
      "orderable": true,
    },{
      "width": "10%", 
      "orderable": true,
    },{
      "width": "15%",
      "orderable": true,
    },{
      "width": "10%",  
      "orderable": true,
    },{
      "width": "5%",  
      "className": "dt-center",
      "targets": 'no-sort', 
      "orderable": false,
    }
  ],
});
```

but the table display width is different. Image attached here.

[image]

Why this one is not working? Anything wrong with the query? kindly help.

Comment: Are you using any plugin like `jqGrid` or `dataTables`?

Comment: sry I am new to jquery. I dont know about jqgrid.. but in some places we user var table = $('#Details').DataTable(); to create table.

Comment: That means you are using `dataTables`. Please provide more code so that we can help you out.

Comment: ** table.dataTable {
            clear: both;
            margin-top: 6px !important;
            margin-bottom: 6px !important;
            max-width: none !important;
        }** This is the code used under <style> tag. other than this we used  _var t= $('#Details').DataTable();_  whererever we wanna create we used t.draw();  and wherever we wanna clear we used t.clear()..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
$('#Details').dataTable({
 "columnDefs": [
  {
    "width": "30%",  
    "orderable": true,
    "targets": 0
  },{
    "width": "10%", 
    "orderable": true,
    "targets": 1
  },{
    "width": "10%", 
    "orderable": true,
    "targets": 2
  },{
    "width": "10%", 
    "orderable": true,
    "targets": 3
  },{
    "width": "10%", 
    "orderable": true,
    "targets": 4
  },{
    "width": "15%",
    "orderable": true,
    "targets": 5
  },{
    "width": "10%",  
    "orderable": true,
    "targets": 6
  },{
    "width": "5%",  
    "className": "dt-center",
    "targets": 7, 
    "orderable": false,
  }
 ],
});
```

**Reference Document:** https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30530/set-fixed-column-width

Hope this will help you.

Comment: but thanks for your reference link..  I added "targets ":0 ... "targets":7 next to my width size, (saw in ur link question) .. now its working thank you..

Comment: so for my question above one is not the right answer.. can you update plz? then I will tick as crct answer..

Comment: @Halim Welcome buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS and it'll set yout table layout as you assigned it:

```
#Details{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed; // ***********add this
  word-wrap:break-word; // ***********and this
}
```